# How to test an interaction (difference between differences) using contrasts in R

Tags: r, lme4, interaction, mixed-models, contrast

I would like to figure out whether the difference between the average of two variables is greater/less than the difference between the average of two different variables.

I have a 4 by 4 within-subject completely crossed design with a binary dependent variable that I modeled with a generalized mixed-effect linear model (using a log link-function) with random by-subject and by-item intercepts using lme4.

The first variable (Character) has levels: extremely good character, mildly good character, extremely bad character, and mildly bad character

The second variable (Outcome) has levels: extremely good outcome, mildly good outcome, extremely bad outcome, and mildly bad outcome.

Participants made a forced choice yes/no decision about whether the characters deserved several outcomes. I coded "yes" responses as 1 and "no" responses as 0. Thus, the model predicted the proportion of participants judging an outcome as deserved. Higher proportions represent higher proportion of participants rating an outcome as deserved for a character type.

There were 8 items in each character-outcome condition (e.g., 8 items where an extremely good character experienced a mildly negative outcome).

[Here is a graph of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBsbW.png)

What I am interested in is whether the difference between positive outcomes (average of extremely positive and mildly positive outcomes) and negative outcomes (average of extremely negative and mildly negative outcomes) is greater for positive characters (average of extremely positive and mildly positive characters) compared to negative characters (average of extremely negative and mildly negative characters).

The graph suggests that this should be so. Participants judged positive characters as highly deserving of positive outcomes (avg prop = .965) and not deserving of negative outcomes (avg prop = .039). That's a .926 difference. In contrast, participants judged negative characters as only slightly deserving positive outcomes on average (avg prop = .59) and as slightly undeserving of negative outcomes on average (avg prop = .39). That's a .20 difference.

Thus, what I want to do is test whether the .926 difference between positive and negative outcomes for positive characters is sig. greater than the .20 difference between positive and negative outcomes for negative characters.

Right now, I've been using the "contrast" function from the lsmeans package to calculate whether there is a difference for positive and negative outcomes separately for extremely positive/negative characters and mildly positive/negative characters. This does not quite get at the question I want to ask. I will provide some code to show how I have done this.

First, here is the data: [download as csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SkV58D9BqkWE9419g5ETrn6KHSZJlcxFZYGCQ6pWqu0/edit?usp=sharing)

Now some R code that you can copy/paste:

```
Data <- read.csv(file.choose())

require(lme4)
require(lsmeans)

Model <- glmer(Choice ~ Character*Outcome + (1|Item) + (1|Subject), dat=Data, family="binomial", control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))

lsmip(Model, Character~Outcome, type="response") #Plot of the data

Model.means <- lsmeans(Model, specs = c("Character", "Outcome"), type="response")

levels(interaction(Data$Character,Data$Outcome)) #to help with the contrasts

#Here are the contrasts that I am currently using

contrast(Model.means, list(ExtPosChar.vs.MildPosChar.for.GoodOutcomes = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,.5,0,-.5,0,.5,0,-.5),
ExtPosChar.vs.MildPosChar.for.BadOutcomes = c(0,.5,0,-.5,0,.5,0,-.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))

contrast(Model.means, list(ExtNegChar.vs.MildNegChar.for.GoodOutcomes = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,.5,0,-.5,0,.5,0,-.5,0),
ExtNegChar.vs.MildNegChar.for.BadOutcomes = c(.5,0,-.5,0,.5,0,-.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for `contrast`, and in particular the optional `interaction` argument -- which generates interaction contrasts. There are examples there and in the vignette "using-lsmeans"